# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooService': No qualifying bean of type [aaa.FooService] found for dependency [aaa.FooService]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have encountered this weird behavior of Spring in Spring boot 1.4.0. Spring basically tells me that it cannot autowire a bean to the resource, because it did not found itself for dependency.

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 
'fooService': No qualifying bean of type [**aaa.FooService**] found for dependency [**aaa.FooService**]
```

FooService is autowired in the resource. When I @Autowire it into @Configuration file, which creates the resource, it is injected there as expected.

This works:

```
public class ServiceMocksRestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private FooService fooService; //instance here

@Bean
public FooResource fooResource() {
    return new FooResource(); // debuger stop here
}
```

//Debugger step into

```
@RestController
public class FooResource {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService; //bang
```

Does someone has any idea, what might went wrong?

Funny stuff is that when I run the app from tests using boot spring runner, it also works (everything, including this resource)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed today to find the root cause. Its Spring Boot devtools - more precisely its split classloader (related bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3316)

When I put a breakpoint in ListableBeanFactory when the child REST @Configuration was about to @Autowire the FooService

and did FooService instanceof FooServiceInterface, it returned false.
And when I did FooService.class.getClassLoader() and beanfactory.getBean("fooService" /*cannot use class here, would trigger not found exception*/).getClass().getClassloader() these were different (one was AppClassLoader and the other was devtools restartable class loader).

Solution: remove boot devtools from classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason for this is that, there is no bean initialized for type `FooService` inside the Spring IOC container at the moment the run-time tries to autowire `FooService` into `ServiceMocksRestConfig` .

It can be cause by different mistakes in development. This [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception) addresses each and every possible mistakes that can cause this problem.